# How to serve regional content to search engine spiders?

Tags: seo

I currently have a single domain `www.mydomain.com`

This performs geolocation and shows you the content that is relevant to your country.

This means that search engines also get served regional content when indexing. However, my problem is that `google.co.uk` is showing the U.S. content (because I identify the Googlebot as in the U.S.).

What can I do about this?

How do I tell the bot that there is different content for different countries?

I don't want to have multiple domain suffixes (e.g. `mydomain.de`, `mydomain.co.uk`)

and I'd rather not use subdomains, although I will if I have to (although how does Google know that `uk.mydomain.com` is the UK version of `us.mydomain.com` and not end up listing both in both regions?)

Are there any alternatives? Do bots identify what region they're crawling for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either subdomains or subfolders (`mydomain.com/uk/`), but in either case you should do the following two things:

1. Use [`rel="alternate" hreflang="x"`](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077) on the `<html>` head section of your domain root for each version to specify the language and the country. Alternatively, you can do the same thing [with an XML sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2620865).
2. Verify the different subdomains/subfolders as different "sites" in Google Webmaster Tools, and then [set a geographic target](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399) for each one of them.

Hreflang example:

```
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://mydomain.com/uk/” hreflang=”en-gb” />
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate domains are the best option (you can easily have multiple sitemaps etc.). This automatically gives best results in the specific search engine (yourpage.de goes to google.de).

But if you don't want this solution, your only option is to specify the language in the HTML attributes, meta tags, depeding on the (X)HTML version you use.

Besides, Google has a very good language detection algorithms. See the [Google information about geotargeting](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399)

The worst option is cloaking (serving different content on the same url). If this is what you want, you may consiter something like Google Website Optimizer.